# How to generate combinations of case with r

Tags: r, math, statistics

a supermarket trying to analyze the behavior of their customers, they make a survey about their preference over what they buy within what they buy if they put all the items on the same rack.
A: I will grab the item to my shopping bag
B: I will be confused
C: Too much item I see, I will buy neither

```
    Candy      Chocolate
Amy    B          A
Diana  C          C
Kate   A          B
Harry  C          B
```

Our data scientist say we will pick the lowest score within our conclusion

```
    Candy      Chocolate    Conclusion
Amy    B          A            B 
Diana  C          C            C
Kate   A          B            B
Harry  C          B            C
```

Thus we will have "case"

```
candy < chocolate
candy = chocolate
candy > chocolate
```

where we have "test case"

```
A<B
A=B
A>B
A<C
A=C
...
```

Because there are too many "test case", I want to do unique case sampling
as for example

```
B<A = C<B
(Equal Case)
```

How can I generate this unique test case? where same case should not duplicated when i run the test

As the value can be more than A,B,C, there maybe D and the fields can be more than candy or chocolate

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking... could you give us some data to replicate your problem with and explain what result you'd hope to get with that data?

Comment: I want to run "test", that test must "cover" all possible "cases" but the test don't have to run all "test case"

Comment: I'm still not totally clear what you need. Would using the "unique" function work?

Comment: Sorry, no, I want to generate [Functional completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness). In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set.